# SyntaxError: can't assign to operator (python)

Tags: python

For some reason, the code below doesn't work:

```
a=10
b=1
if ((a)/(b))==0:(a/b)=10

Output: SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

I'm not exactly sure where the error is.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: (a/b)=1 is the error, but I'm not sure what you're trying to do there.

Comment: What do you expect `(a/b)=1` to do?

Comment: just edited it. I'm trying to avoid having a logarithm of zero.

Comment: @Tiger1 In that case, I'd suggest assigning a different values to a or raising appropriate error or something. a/b is defined by a and b, so assigning a value to a/b itself doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks @Yosh, I have figured it out. By assigning (a/b) to a variable before enforcing the constraint is just what I was looking for. ie j=(a/b)

Answer (score 2):

In `(a/b)=1`, you're trying to assign a 1 to the expression `(a/b)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
a=10
b=1

j=(a/b)

if j==0:j=10
```

By assigning (a/b) to a variable j, the if statement can be enforced.